# Customize Strapi default permission error return

Tags: javascript, customization, return-value, strapi

Is there a way to edit the default error return by Strapi for permission / token error?

For example, in roles & permissions under Public role, I uncheck the route for `send-email-confirmation`.  If I use postman and try doing `localhost:1337/auth/send-email-confirmation`, I would get such error return

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
}
```

I believe this is the default `middleware / policy` I know where I can get the default `send-email-confirmation` controller and edit it, but that is only if `Roles & Permissions` are enabled / checked inside public role.

Same as if a route requires `headers` of `Authorization` token but if it is not provided, a default error will be given again which I am not able to find where to customize it.

I don't seem to find it inside strapi documentation or maybe I am using the wrong key words to search.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions + advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auth token - permissions validation and errors are managed in this file - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/0c6d39297f6f8a4f983e22fb48256b42da2a8605/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/config/policies/permissions.js#L15

If you want to update this file, you will have to follow the customization concept - https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/customization.html#plugin-extensions

With this, you will be able to change the error message.

Comment: O.o weird, I thought I have tried this file already because I already added it into my project and changed something in there.  Anyways, works like a charm now.  Thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: What if a route does not exist? A return of `{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Not Found"
}` would be returned if it does not exist.  But this does not belong to any plugin-extensions does it?

Answer (score 0):

### **Create custom error response files**

In folder `config/functions/responses/`, create corresponding files with relevant filename matching the error code. Inside you can inspect the event and return a custom response. This works for me using Strapi `3.6.8`. I'm not sure of latest Strapi. [Here's an older doc page](https://strapi.gitee.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/responses.html) with error codes as reference.

Create files in this format for a variety of error codes...

**Examples:**

config/functions/responses/404.js

```
'use strict'

module.exports = async (ctx) => {

    // Do other stuff
    console.log("404 response is: %O, ctx)

    // Return a specific error format (e.g. 'notFound') with your own custom message
    return ctx.notFound('My custom 404 message')

}
```

config/functions/responses/403.js

```
'use strict'

module.exports = async (ctx) => {

    // Do other stuff
    console.log("403 response is: %O, ctx)

    // Return a specific error format (e.g. 'forbidden') with your own custom message
    return ctx.forbidden('My custom 403 message')

}
```